# How to add animations between pages in gartsby with Gsap

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gsap

I want to add animation between pages in gatsby using Gsap.

Im trying to follow their docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/

At some point they say: **Finally, import the TransitionLink component wherever you want to use it...**
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/#getting-started

But I dont know where to use, should it be used in the actual pages components or in the Layout component?(I want to have disfferent animations for each page though)

I want to use the trigger function:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/#using-the-trigger-function
Because I want to use Gsap.

But then they just write in the code **"someCustomDefinedAnimation"** but I dont know where is that coming from, how do i create one and how do I pass it through props.

```
<TransitionLink
  exit={{
    length: length,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.someCustomDefinedAnimation({ exit, node, direction: "out" }),
  }}
  entry={{
    length: 0,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.someCustomDefinedAnimation({ exit, node, direction: "in" }),
  }}
  {...props}
>
  {props.children}
</TransitionLink>
```

So my questions are:

- Where should I add the TransitionLink component?
- How do I create a custom Gsap animation?
- Where and how do i pass animation this as props so that TransitionLink can use it?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant (I haven't used Gatsby) but GreenSock just put out a [React-specific article](https://greensock.com/react/).

Answer (score 0):

> But then they just write in the code `someCustomDefinedAnimation` but
> I dont know where is that coming from, how do i create one and how do
> I pass it through props.

Well, `someCustomDefinedAnimation` is just a defined function that contains the animation. For example:

```
  verticalAnimation = ({ length, direction}) => {
    const directionTo = direction === 'up' ? '-100%' : '100%'
    const directionFrom = direction === 'up' ? '100%' : '-100%'

    // convert ms to s for gsap
    const seconds = length

    return gsap.timeline()
      .set(this.transitionCover, { y: directionFrom })
      .to(this.transitionCover, {
        y: '0%',
        ease: "power1.easeInOut",
        duration: seconds / 2,
      })
      .set(this.layoutContents, { opacity: 0 })
      .to(this.transitionCover, {
        y: directionTo,
        ease: "power1.easeIn",
        duration: seconds / 2,
      })
  }
```

Then you'll need to use it as:

```
<TransitionLink
  exit={{
    length: length,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.verticalAnimation({length: 100, direction: 'up'}),
  }}
  entry={{
    length: 0,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.verticalAnimation({length: 100, direction: "down" }),
  }}
  {...props}
>
  {props.children}
</TransitionLink>
```

Basically, it allows you to fully customize the function triggered in each page transition

You can find a detailed explanation and walkthrough in [`TransitionLink` docs](https://transitionlink.tylerbarnes.ca/docs/transitionlink/) and an implementation example at their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/tree/master/example).